# Can i use vtkGlyph3D without a SourceConnection?

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to create a `vtkGlyph3D` from a `vtkPolyData` containing points, triangles and colors

```
polydata->SetPoints(points);
polydata->SetPolys(triangles);
polydata->GetPointData()->SetScalars(colors);
```

Now in all the examples for `vtkGlyph3D` there is always the call to `SetSourceConnection` to which a `vtkAlgorithmOutput` object is passed.

Since i don't use a `vtkCubeSource` or `vtkConeSource` or the like, i don't know what i should pass here.
Can i just omit this call and simply do this

```
vtkNew<vtkGlyph3D> glyph3D;
glyph3D->SetColorModeToColorByScalar();
glyph3D->SetInputData(polydata);
glyph3D->ScalingOff();
glyph3D->Update();
```

to build my glyph?

Or do i somehow have to create a `vtkAlgorithmOutput` from my polydata?

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGlyph3D.html#details), vtkGlyph3D

> copy oriented and scaled glyph geometry to every input point

In other word, this filter copy the `Source` geometry on every (Nth) points of your `Input` (and some more option of scale / orientation). So it does not make sense to use it without a `SetSourceConnection` (with any kind of source/reader/filter providing a polydata)

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. In the mean time i have implemented a new Source object (based on ```vtkCylinderSource```) which sends its output to  a ```vtkGlyph3DMapper```. The geometries are drawn correctly, but i've still got issues with the  colors. But i think for that i'll have to open a new post

Comment: If this first question is solved, you may accept the answer.